# QScrollBar button size

Tags: qt, styles, qscrollbar

I'm creating a GUI in QtDesigner and did some styling on the window itself made everything have font size 30pt and QScrollBars width and height (vertical and horizontal respectively) 90px. For simplicity i'll continue with vertical scrollbars, but translate everything to horizontal ones too. Now the buttons at the ends of the scrollbar are slim as they heights remained the same (and i presume the slider itself has minimum height lower than 90px). Styling those buttons did not yield any results. Could someone please tell me, what should i do to make those buttons (and the minimum slider height) bigger, so that it could be used on a 1024x600, 7" touch monitor? Qt version 5.11.3, and using python, PySide2.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To set the width of all vertical scrollbars of widget w and its children:

`w.setStyleSheet('QScrollBar:vertical {width: 40px;}')`

for the height of horizontal ones:

`w.setStyleSheet('QScrollBar:horizotal {height: 40px;}')`

Answer (score 0):

You can style the QScollbars buttons size by the css selectors **QScrollBar::add-line:vertical** and **QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical**.
I apply the style on Bars like this:

```
QScrollBar:vertical
{
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background: white;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 52px 0px 52px 0px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical
{
    background: grey;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical
{
    background: none;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical
{
    height: 50px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical
{
    height: 50px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
```

Further styling on **add-line** and **sub-line** (like adding borders...) may remove the default scrollbar arrows that is why I left this out.

Comment: What is the advantage of this approach compared to the other answers? Is all this styling needed to solve the question of YaniMan? Please remove all unnecessary code from your answer to solve the issue raised by the OP and/or create a new question stating the problem you encounters and answer your own question.

Comment: Actually, the other answer does not solve the problem stated by YaniMan. Applying the answer of Giovanni Angeli will just scale the bars theirself but not the buttons at the ends of the bars (and that is the point of the question, scaling those buttons). 
My answer is a bit long that is true. It is because some other things than just scaling has to be done in order to leave those buttons visible after they have been scaled (like setting the margin in the QScrollBar::vertical). 
I will edit this to be more clear and remove unnecessary stuffs.